# Add folder to PYTHONPATH programmatically

Tags: python, windows, pythonpath

The environment variable `PYTHONPATH` is set to `C:\Users\Me`. I'd like to add to `PYTHONPATH` a folder named `code` which is located in the same directory as my script (`D:\Project`). This is what I tried:

##### `test.py`

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

print('BEFORE:', os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])

folder = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.joinpath('code')
print('FOLDER:', folder)

os.system(f'set PYTHONPATH={folder};%PYTHONPATH%')
print('AFTER:', os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])
```

###### Sample run:

```
D:\Project> dir /ad /b
code

D:\Project> dir *.py /b
test.py

D:\Project> python test.py
BEFORE: C:\Users\Me
FOLDER: D:\Project\code
AFTER: C:\Users\Me     <<< should be D:\Project\code;C:\Users\Me
```

I also tried this:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["set", f"PYTHONPATH={folder};%PYTHONPATH%"])
```

And this is what I got:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

How can I add a folder to `PYTHONPATH` programmatically?
I want to change the system environment variable only for the execution of the current script

Comment: Are you wanting to change the value in `os.environ` or the system environment variable? If it's the latter, should it be a permanent change or temporary (i.e. only for the execution of the current script)?

Comment: I want to change the system environment variable only for the execution of the current script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to change it for the execution of the current script, you can do it simply by assigning (or changing an existing) value in the `os.environ` mapping. The code below is complicated a bit by the fact that I made it work even if `os.environ[PYTHONPATH]` **isn't** initially set to anything (as is the case on my own system).

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

PYTHONPATH = 'PYTHONPATH'

try:
    pythonpath = os.environ[PYTHONPATH]
except KeyError:
    pythonpath = ''

print('BEFORE:', pythonpath)

folder = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.joinpath('code')
print(f'{folder=}')

pathlist = [str(folder)]
if pythonpath:
    pathlist.extend(pythonpath.split(os.pathsep))
print(f'{pathlist=}')

os.environ[PYTHONPATH] = os.pathsep.join(pathlist)
print('AFTER:', os.environ[PYTHONPATH])
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe `sys.path.append(...)` should work.
Don't forget to import `sys`.

Comment: This does not answer my question as I want to change `PYTHONPATH` rather than `PATH`.

Comment: @Tonechas It [does](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

Comment: @PeterBadida: The OP wants to change the value of an environment variable programmatically, so no it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

[`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) as well as [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) do set the thing you want. You are just missing two things:

- an environment variable is set per process, thus not accessible from outside of the process except after the process ends
- [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) executes in a new subshell, thus the env var isn't affected for your process. It's affected *in the subshell* which then exits.

```sh
C:\> set PYTHONPATH=hello; python
>>> from os import environ
>>> environ["PYTHONPATH"]
'hello'
>>> environ["PYTHONPATH"] = environ["PYTHONPATH"] + ";world"
>>> environ["PYTHONPATH"]
'hello;world'
>>> 
C:\> echo %PYTHONPATH%
# empty or "%PYTHONPATH%" string
```

For preserving the value you need to utilize **the shell** which is the thing that manipulates the environment. For example with `export` (or `set` on Windows):

```sh
set PYTHONPATH=hello
echo %PYTHONPATH%
# hello
python -c "print('set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;world')" > out.bat
out.bat
echo %PYTHONPATH%
# hello;world
```

Alternatively, utilize `subprocess.Popen(["command"], env={"PYTHONPATH": environ["PYTHONPATH"] + <separator> + new path})` which will basically open a new process - i.e. you can create a Python launcher for some other program and prepare the environment for it this way. The environment in it will be affected, yet the environment outside still won't as for that you still need to have access to the shell from the shell's process context, not from the child (python process).

More on that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/372628/296803) and [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150915-00/?p=91591).

Example:

```py
# launcher.py
from subprocess import Popen

Popen(["python", "-c", "import os;print(os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'))"])

Popen(
    ["python", "-c", "import os;print(os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'))"],
    env={"PYTHONPATH": "hello"}
)
```

Comment: A.) This is not an answer and B.) the OP is using Windows.

Comment: Updated for Windows. The rest doesn't really change. Manipulating it programatically was fine with sys or os, though you are correct when it's about preserving the value in the parent process - explained further.

Comment: @Tonechas check the update on the answer and especially the linked part as Unix StackExchange. Same applies for Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found the command `python -c "print('set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;world')" > out.bat` to be particularly insighful for figuring out the issue.